# How to align an element in the center in Xamarin iOS for all screen sizes?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I have been trying to keep a logo in the center on the screen for all apple screen sizes but it just doesn't seem to work when the logo is small. As I understand , its probably because the left, right, top, bottom margin constrains are absolute and not relative.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

[image]
[image]

When I change Generic to iPhone 5s in simulator :
[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AngXV.png)

Comment: Add a constraint for center in parent rather than top/left constraints

Comment: Apply fix height and width of your image view and set vertically and horizontally 0 to your superview

Comment: @iPatel it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ Sami Kuhmonen mentioned, Add a constraint for center instead.

[image]

#### How to add?

Drag the pin(locate in the center) to the vertical and horizontal line.
[image]

Click this button to update the frame:

[image]

Comment: What is the  superview of  image?

Comment: another image (background image)

Comment: @Arbaaz select the  outermost View ,and click the update frame button.

Comment: I have found that it works if I keep the height and width fixed. But what if I want the image to resize according to the screen size?

Comment: @the  the size of `UIImageView` is according to the image file in your project folder. You should change the size of  image file instead of setting fixed height and width.

Comment: You don't need to set the height and width constraint on `UIButton `, `UILabel` , `UIImageView `, because they will resize according to its content.  But of course you can also set fixed size on them.

Comment: after  1 hour I realize to  push the update button... TX